# Keycloak change registration flow / create user API

Tags: node.js, keycloak

Lately, I am playing with keylock server. I have an application which has a bit of complication in the registration flow, and I need to change the basic flow of keycloak. Is this possible? For example, when a user fills the needed data, and 
 clicks to register, I want to redirect him directly to my site and not to keycloak server ( profile manager ).

Also, I am trying to add a user via API, using 'node.js', which would be the easiest way. However, it seems I can't get it done. Does anyone have or know of some kind of tutorial, that can help me, or point me in the right direction?

EDIT:

What I tried is create bash script and add user via rest

```
#!/bin/bash

export TKN=$(curl -X POST 'http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token' \
 -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
 -d "username=admin" \
 -d 'password=admin' \
 -d 'grant_type=password' \
 -d 'client_id=admin-cli' | jq -r '.access_token')


curl -X POST 'http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/demo/users' \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-d "username=abc
-H "Authorization: Bearer $TKN" | jq .
```

It doesn't throw any error. But in keycloak I can't see any new user.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @CharlieFish Sorry It was not my intention to break any rule. I added bash script how I tried to add a user via rest API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this possible? For example, when a user fills the needed data, and clicks to register, I want to redirect him directly to my site and not to keycloak server ( profile manager ).

Yes. You can add a user via REST API.

> Also, I am trying to add a user via API, using 'node.js', which would be the easiest way. However, it seems I can't get it done. Does anyone have or know of some kind of tutorial, that can help me, or point me in the right direction?

This is an example how to create a user using Keycloak REST API:
https://github.com/v-ladynev/keycloak-nodejs-example/blob/master/lib/adminClient.js#L35

> It doesn't throw any error. But in keycloak I can't see any new user.

Looks like, you provided incorrect parameters, or didn't provide mandatory parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking can be broken down to two questions...

1. how to change the flow ( This is what i m currently trying to find out),
2. what keycloak command line commands allow for user registration etc.
   These should be the [CLI commands](https://wjw465150.gitbooks.io/keycloak-documentation/content/server_admin/topics/admin-cli.html) e.g. [client-registration-cli](https://wjw465150.gitbooks.io/keycloak-documentation/content/securing_apps/topics/client-registration/client-registration-cli.html) though there is as you say a REST API as well.

Comment: I think I never got to that, It should be doable if you search for the keyword, but at the time it was enough to change the look&feel for the login pages etc

Comment: https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/16.1/rest-api/index.html

Its possible now via API  @ntg

Comment: For change flow via API
```
curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -H "Authorization: Bearer $KEYCLOAK_TOKEN" -d '{"browserFlow": "Custom flow"}' 'http://keycloak:8080/auth/admin/realms/master/'
```
Should do it with admin permission @ntg

Answer (score -1):

you add the role managerusers to your user that you will create the new user with in keycloak